# PayPal API response says payment succeeded but Paypal Sandbox says payment not permitted

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I try to place a payment in the Sandbox using the Paypal Adaptive Payments API, I get a `SUCCESS` response from the API:

```
PayResponse  
paymentExecStatus   CREATED
ack Success
build   2050734
timestamp   2011-09-19T17%3A02%3A23.409-07%3A00
```

However, if the Sandbox user (payment review disabled) is a non-American, the Sandbox won't allow the payment to go all the way through and instead sends the buyer to an Error screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the error you're getting it's guesswork, but I think the account you're using to receive payments likely doesn't payments accept in the currency you're sending it in. Either change this setting in the Profile (Payment Receiving Preferences or Website Payments Preferences) or open a balance in that specific currency.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Good guesswork :) You were correct! I set up a different user in the Sandbox that was configured to receive Euros and that user was able to receive the payments. But in the Sandbox I don't think you have the ability to do what you suggested - namely configure my original receiver to be able to receive multiple currency types. Correct me if I'm wrong but I suspect you're talking about a feature that is only available for an actual "live" account?

Comment: No, that is available for Sandbox accounts as well. Sandbox is really the same beast as the Live environment, except it's not connected to any of the processing networks. No matter, you got it fixed! :-)